# QT server side has error in write function (stopped in thread 0...)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small chat application. I can send data from client to server, but I can not send data from server to client.
this is my server code :
    .pro

```
QT       += core 
QT       += network
QT       -= gui

TARGET = QServer
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    tcpserver.cpp

HEADERS += \
    tcpserver.h

//===========================TCPServer.h


#ifndef TCPSERVER_H
#define TCPSERVER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>

class TCPServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TCPServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~TCPServer();
signals:

public slots:
    void newConnection();
    void disconnected();
    void readyRead();
    void writeData(QString data);

private:
    QTcpServer *serv;
    QTcpSocket *socket;
};
#endif // TCPSERVER_H

//===========================TCPServer.cpp


#include "tcpserver.h"

TCPServer::TCPServer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    serv=new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(serv,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(newConnection()));
    if(!serv->listen(QHostAddress::Any,3490))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Server Error in Connecting...."<<serv->errorString();
    }
    else
        qDebug()<<"Server Started     :)     ";
}

TCPServer::~TCPServer()
{
    disconnected();
}

void TCPServer::newConnection()
{
    socket=serv->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
    socket->write("Hello Client");
    socket->flush();//clean the buffer
    socket->waitForReadyRead(3000);
   // sock->close();
}

void TCPServer::disconnected()
{
    socket->close();
    qDebug()<<"Good By     :)     ";
}

void TCPServer::readyRead()
{
    //qDebug()<<"Server is Reading ...."<<socket->readAll();
    while(socket->canReadLine())
    {
        QByteArray ba = socket->readLine();
        if(strcmp(ba.constData(), "!exit\n") == 0)
        {
            socket->disconnectFromHost();
            break;
        }
        //printf(">> %s", ba.constData());
        qDebug() << "Server is receiving ...."<<ba.constData();
    }
}


void TCPServer::writeData(QString data)
{
    socket->write(data.toStdString().c_str());
    socket->flush();//clean the buffer
    socket->waitForReadyRead(3000);
}


//===========================TCPServer/main.cpp


#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "tcpserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    TCPServer srv;
//    while(1)
//    {
        QTextStream s(stdin);
        QString value = s.readLine();
        srv.writeData(value);
//    }
```

my server can receive data from client and shows it very well. but when I want send data from server to client it shows me this error :

> stopped in thread 0 by : exception at 0x5118cf9a, code : 0xc0000005:
>   read access violation at 0x0x, flags=0x0 (first chance)

.
what does it mean?
Where is my error in write data on socket?

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash in action? Then you can see where in your code it happens, and also examine variables to see that their values look okay.

Comment: sorry. how to do that? I put try catch. but no error shows to me

Comment: Your IDE should have a button or menu alternative to run in the debugger. Start there.

Comment: "read access violation at 0x0x" - in case it wasn't obvious, that would be a NULL pointer dereference. I'd definitely debug this, as it is highly likely you'll catch it there, but barring that I'd instrument and test.

Comment: When I trace my code in debugger it shows that error in socket->write(data.toStdString().c_str(),data.length()); this line. ( I said this line has error and server can not run this function)

Comment: Is it possible the socket is null?

Comment: yes, my socket is null in server. but why?

Comment: Perhaps you're calling `TCPServer::writeData` before any client has connected to it?

Comment: yes. I think this code is make a waiting    ( QTextStream s(stdin);
        QString value = s.readLine();) for user input.so is it true to define read from socket in one thread and write on socket in another thread in console chat application?

Comment: You could handle user input in a new thread, or move your `TCPServer` to a new thread. But don't try to read from a socket in one thread and write to it in another.

Comment: Sorry . but I can not do that. I want to put this code to thread (//    while(1)     {        QTextStream s(stdin);        QString value = s.readLine();        srv.writeData(value);    } ). how to do that?

Comment: You do not want to do that. Just move the input handling to a new thread and emit a signal from that thread every time you receive some input. [Here](http://cpp.sh/76jbj) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I move the input handling to a new thread and emit a signal from that thread every time you receive some input. (as [thuga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257050/thuga) answer)